# Best database design for website ranking

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance, database-recommendation, query-performance

I am working on a project in which I need to rank websites in two way - Global rank and their rank in a particular country. There are various factors based on which both are calculated. There are ~200 countries for which rank needs to be calculated.

*I am using MySQL*

I have two questions -

**Global rank**

Whenever any new website is added -

- Either I need to recalculate the ranks for all the website if I store the website rank in database. This requires a lot of processing each time a new website is added.
- or the other option is to assign a score to each website and whenever query is made assign rank by doing `order by` based on score, and returning its position. This doesn't seem scalable way as `order by` is expensive operation.

**Country Rank database and updation**

- How should I store per country rank of each website ?
- How to update all these ranks when a new website is added ? Here the updation will be even more costly than in case of Global rank.
- Should I generate it `on-the-fly` when queried and then cache the result ?

How do websites like play store show personalized and country based results ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will you be ranking the *billions* of web sites?  If so, then on-the-fly and recompute-all are out of the question.

Instead, have a background task working on the problem.  For display, show the info that is in the table, possibly out of date by a day or two (depending on how long it takes to recalc).

Put the ranking in a separate table, with only `website_id` and `rank`.  This will make *replacing* the entire table after the recalc atomic and fast.  Perhaps a second table with `website_id`, `country_code` (`CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii`), and `rank`.

You have not explained how the ranking is calculated, so I can't give you any insight in how to do it as a background task.

Comment: There are certain factors like google page rank, website loading time, ranking from third party apis , whether its listed in dmoz or not , etc. using which I calculate score out of 100.00(float field ) for each website. This is a different table with website_id and factors based on which score is calculated. And then based on score I can update ranking in another table with website_id and rank. Is that the best way ?

Comment: Off hand, it seems like the best way.